# Android ViewPager get view nullpointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have support.v4 **ViewPager**, which I fill with fragments, by using **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**.

The displaying of the fragments in ViewPager works as expected, but the problem is getting the fragment views when calling the `getView()` function in the FragmentActvitiy class. I can access all the 15 fragments and get arguments, etc.., but when calling getView() function on fragment I get a **nullpointer exception**, becase the third fragment getView() is `null`.

```
MyPageAdapter adapter = (MyPageAdapter) pager.getAdapter();
Fragment fragment;

for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
    fragment = adapter.getItem(i);
    View v = fragment.getView();
    System.out.println("--- FRAGMENT = " + fragment + "   VIEW = " + v);
}
```

Output:

```
--- FRAGMENT = MyPrvaPomocFragment{40ede4c8 #0 id=0x7f06000d}   VIEW = android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout{40f11cb0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-540,850}
--- FRAGMENT = MyPrvaPomocFragment{40edf7c0 #1 id=0x7f06000d}   VIEW = android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout{40f16f80 V.E..... ......ID 540,0-1080,850}
--- FRAGMENT = MyPrvaPomocFragment{40ee0998}   VIEW = null
```

**FragmentStatePageAdapter class code:**

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

**Fragment class code:**

```
public class MyPrvaPomocFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_QUESTION_NUMBER = "EXTRA_QUESTION_NUMBER";
    public static final String EXTRA_QUESTION = "EXTRA_QUESTION";
    ...    

    public static final MyPrvaPomocFragment newInstance(String questionNumber, String question, ..., int correctAnswer) {
        MyPrvaPomocFragment f = new MyPrvaPomocFragment();

        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_QUESTION_NUMBER, questionNumber);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_QUESTION, question);
        bdl.putInt(EXTRA_CORRECT_ANSWER, correctAnswer);
        ...
        f.setArguments(bdl);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String question = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_QUESTION);
        String firstAnswer = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_FIRST_ANSWER);
        ...

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prva_pomoc, container, false);

        TextView textViewQuestion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        ...

        textViewQuestion.setText(question);
        checkBox1.setText(firstAnswer);
        checkBox2.setText(secondAnswer);

        return v;
    }
}
```

**FragmentActivity class code:**

```
public class KvizPrvaPomoc extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager pager;
    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;    

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kviz_prva_pomoc);

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpagerquiz);              
        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getFragments());
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }  

    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
        String question;
        String firstAnswer;
        String secondAnswer;
        ...

        List<Fragment> fragmentList  = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        for (int j=0; j<someList.size(); j++)  { 
            ...  
            fragmentList.add(MyPrvaPomocFragment.newInstance(questionNumber, question, firstAnswer, ...));
        }

        return fragmentList;
    }
}
```

I have read through numerous SO questions/answers, but I have no idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior; `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` destroys fragments once you scroll more than one fragment away from them in either direction. This is done to conserve memory.

Comment: So there is no way for me to access the fragments widgets (EditText, CheckBox,..) inside the ViewPager?

Comment: You (sometimes) can, but only when the Fragment's view has been created and not yet been destroyed. You can check if the retrieved `View` is null before you attempt to access any of its subviews. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Fragments' views are removed from memory by view pager automatically. This is done to manage resources on mobiles.

You should not try to access visual elements of the fragments from the activity anyway. Only fragment should use its own visual elements, not its parent activity directly.

If you need to manipulate fragments, you should change the data they hold and when the view is recreated (when the user swipes to the fragment), it should restore the view properly based on the data.